# performance between creating objects and moving them in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a couple of arc widgets on a tkinter canvas that I draw with [create_arc](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_arc.html). I need to move them. Currently, I am deleting them and recreating them with the `create_arc` method. This works better than using the `.move()` method. I was wondering if there are any performance issues with using this method? Will this bite me back when I have thousands of widgets on a canvas?

Comment: Well, the simplest way to know is to put thousands of widgets on the canvas, and see if it bites you back :-). But what do you mean by "it works better than using the `.move()` method"? Could you explain _how_ it works better? For example, does the `.move()` method glitch more?

Comment: I'm using the `.coords()` method to get the current position, then substract that from the previous position and the use the result to move the widgets. Turns out the `.coords()` method is not accurate bc x0,x1,y0,y1 is always off by 1. I tried finding something about this online but couldn't and eventually jsut got so frustrated that I decided to delete and redraw it on each cycle.

Comment: Hmm... I'd try getting the `coords()` method to work again (maybe the problem was caused by the canvas not being updated when `.coords()` was called). If you take a look at the full-code example at the end of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72080679/16775594) I wrote recently, you can change the `360` in the `for` loop to however many lines you want to create, and on my computer it starts noticeably lagging at about 2,000 lines. So it really depends on how many lines you want to draw.